# Unwanted Exponential Output in Matlab computation

Tags: matlab

I am solving multiple regression problem using vectors entered at run time. Some of the output variables default to exponential format and inspection with manual cal shows they're wrong. I underestimated it; spent all day yesterday to debug and fix it without success hence I am sharing it. I've commented on the wrong outputs below. Thanks, in advance.

```
x1 = input('Enter x1 data:');
x2 = input('Enter x2 data:');
y = input('Enter y data:');
a = mean(x1);
b= mean(x2);
c = mean(y);
mean_of_x1 = a
mean_of_x2 = b
mean_of_y = c
L1= (y-c).^2;
L2= (x1-a).*(x2-b);
L3=(x1-a).^2;
L4= (x2-b).^2;
L5= (x2-b).^2;
L6=  (x1-a).*(y-c);
L7= (x2-b).*(y-c);
table =[y; x1; x2; y-c; (y-c).^2; x1-a; x2-b;(x1-a).*(x2-b);(x1-a).^2;(x2-b).^2; (x1-a).*(y-c);(x2-b).*(y-c)];
fprintf('y, x1, x2, y-c, (y-c).^2, x1-a, x2-b, (x1-a).*(x2-b), (x1-a).^2, (x2-b).^2, (x1-a).*(y-c),(x1-a).*(y-c);(x2-b).*(y-c)\n ')
fprintf('%4.2f %8.2f %10.2f %12.2f %14.2f %16.2f %18.2f %20.2f %22.2f %24.2f %26.2f %28.2f\n', table)
 summation_of_x1 = sum(x1)
 summation_of_x2= sum(x2)
summation_of_y = sum(y)
d = y-c;
summation_of_y_minus_C = sum(d)% OUTPUTS EXPO RESULT
summation_of_y_minus_c_square=sum((y-c).^2)
e = x1-a;
summation_of_x1_minus_A=sum(e)
 f = x2-b ;



summation_of_x2_minus_B = sum(f)% OUTPUTS EXPO RESULT

 summation_of_product_x1_minus_A_and_x2_minus_B = sum((x1-a).*(x2-b))
 Summation_x1_minus_A_square= sum((x1-a).^2)
 Summation_x2_minus_B_Square= sum((x2-b).^2)
 summation_product_x1_minus_A_and_y_minus_c = sum((x1-a).*(y-c))
 summation_product_x2_minus_B_and_y_minus_c = sum((x2-b).*(y-c))
x1=[3, 1, 9, 5, 2]; x2=[12, 5, 11, 22, 3]; y=[28,9, 5, 7, 32]%My test data
```

Comment: You should place the "test data" at the beginning rather that at the end of your code, and you have to give us the expected output, otherwise no one can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Output should be a decimal number/double. Ignore my test data; code should run with any user-supplied data at run time -Hoki

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the calculations, you are just confused because of the **display format**. I strongly suggest you read the following doc about [`format`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html). As an example, type `format bank` or `format short` in your command window before you run your code, and observe your different outputs.

Comment: Or have a look at `fprintf` for more fine-grained output format control.